# 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'id' #2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have the following entities:

```
public class Entidad
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Propiedad> Propiedades { get; set; }
}

public class Propiedad
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Entidad Entidad { get; set; }

    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string TipoDeDatos { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this controller action

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Entidad = new SelectList(db.Entidades);
    return View();
}
```

and on my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Entidad, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Entidad.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Entidad, "id", "nombre", 0), "Seleccionar", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

However I get this error:
DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'id'.

I also tried with Camel Case Id but still the same.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly you need to change the name of your `ViewBag` property so it does not conflict with your model property (to say `EntidadList`) and then in the `SelectList` constructor, specify the properties to use as the value and text fields

```
ViewBag.EntidadList = new SelectList(db.Entidades, "id", "nombre");
```

Then in the view use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Entidad.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.EntidadList, "Seleccionar", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Notes:

1. `EntidadList` is already a `SelectList` - there is no need to create
   a new one from it.
2. The last parameter in the `SelectList` constructor (where your set
   it to `"0"`) is not required and is ignored. The option that is
   selected in the view is based on the value of `Entidad.Id`
3. Your current usage of `ViewBag.Entidad = new
   SelectList(db.Entidades);` where your do not set the value and text
   fields means its creating `SelectListItems` with a value of
   `System.Web.MVC.SelectListItem>` (a `string`) which does not have a
   property named `id`, hence the error in the view when you attempt to
   create a new `SelectList` from it

Comment: it works, but I get the type instead of the name.  http://screencast.com/t/Z3LDMaJfByS

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a comma (after ViewBag.EntidadList in @DropDownListFor()) and the `new` should no be there

Answer (score 0):

Declare ViewBag.List as `List<>` in the controller.

Then use it to create the select list in the view:

```
new SelectList(Viewbag.List, "ID", "Property", optional selected value)
```